# Lookup Table to choose Column then find nearest value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet that calculates a battery's constant current requirement. I want to be able to find a suitable battery from the set load duration that has a constant current greater or equal to my calculated value.

I'm trying to use a lookup table where my "Load Duration" (Yellow) chooses a column from an array then my Lookup function (Green) finds a value >= to my calculated reference value (Blue). I would also like another function that would find the model from the same row as the found value from the array.

Load Duration is a drop down menu that matches the corresponding columns. I currently have a cell that chooses the column of the array:
`=MATCH(C39,'Battery Lookup Table'!B2:O2,0)`

I have tried multiple lookup functions to find the nearest constant current values:
`=VLOOKUP(C46,'Battery Lookup Table'!B4:O36,MATCH(C39,'Battery Lookup Table'!B2:O2,0),TRUE)`
`=VLOOKUP(C46,'Battery Lookup Table'!B4:O36,N49)`
`=(HLOOKUP(C46,'Battery Lookup Table'!S56:AW69,O50,TRUE))`

Each of these lookup tables have produced the same value.

I have also tried sorting the values from smallest to largest since VLOOKUP and HLOOkUP have a hard time deciphering. I have also tried swapping to rows for the time duration with no luck.

Model Number: `=INDEX('Battery Lookup Table'!A4:A36,MATCH(TRUE,'Battery Lookup Table'!M4:M25>=C46,0))`

Currently my Lookup Function will go to the correct column, but will use a row/value near the bottom of the table more often than not. None of the values that were found were ever the closest value.

[Calculated Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/konYq.png)

[Lookup Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ra4z.png)

[Lookup in Ascending Order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDMgM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` matches a value against the **first** column of a range and delivers the value from a specified column of the range in the matched row. Therefore, your first formula

`=VLOOKUP(C46,'Battery Lookup Table'!B4:O36,MATCH(C39,'Battery Lookup Table'!B2:O2,0),TRUE)`

is matching `C46` (which I think is 500.8 in your example) against the values in range `'Battery Lookup Table'!B4:B36`. This is not the range of you want to be matching against but it probably explains why you are getting your incorrect results.

In fact, you have already identified the correct column to be matching against with your `MATCH` function. You can use the `INDEX` function to select part of a range. The expression

`INDEX('Battery Lookup Table'!B4:O36,,n)`

provides the *n*'th column of `'Battery Lookup Table'!B4:O36` so putting your `MATCH` function in place of *n* provides the correct column of values against which `C46` can be compared. Doing this yields the expression:

`INDEX('Battery Lookup Table'!B4:O36,,MATCH(C39,'Battery Lookup Table'!B2:O2,0))`

To keep things easy to follow I will abbreviate this expression as *list*.

You now want to do 2 things:

1. Find the smallest value in *list* that is greater than or equal to `C46`
2. Find the battery that corresponds to this value.

Here the trick is not to use `VLOOKUP()` but its more flexible "cousin" `INDEX(MATCH())`. Whereas, `VLOOKUP` matches a value on the first column of a range and delivers a value from a column to the right, the more flexible version allows  the value to come from either the same column or one to the left.

Additionally, there are 3 possible ways of matching using `MATCH`, depending whether the value of the third argument is -1,0 or 1. The simplest of these is exact matching which uses the value of 0 (as you have already done when matching against `Battery Lookup Table'!B2:O2`). The value of -1 finds the position of the smallest value in the lookup range that is greater than or equal to the lookup value. This is  your requirement, but it requires the lookup range to be placed in **descending** order. (The value of 1 finds the position of the largest value in the lookup range that is less than or equal to the lookup value and requires the lookup range to be in ascending order - this is not your requirement.)

The values in your `Battery Lookup Table` all appear to be in ascending order so reorganising your data so that the rows appear in reverse order will satisfy the descending order condition - 100G99 will be the first row of data and 50G05 the last. You also need to remove the blank rows as values in these will be treated as zero, so will potentially cause problems by violating the descending order requirement.

The expression

`MATCH(C46,list,-1))`

provides the position in *list* of the value you are looking for and its actual value (for display in your green background cell) is provided by

`=INDEX(list,MATCH(C46,list,-1))`

The battery model is provided by

`=INDEX('Battery Lookup Table'!A4:A46,MATCH(C46,list,-1))`

Substituting the expression for *list* (noted above) into these two formulae results in cumbersome expressions with a degree of repetition in the first one and repeated calculation of `MATCH(C46,list,-1)` across both. These repetitions are not good practice and should, if possible, be avoided.

One way of doing this would be to store in worksheet cells the values of the matching column and row numbers. Respectively, these are:

`=MATCH(C39,'Battery Lookup Table'!B2:O2,0)` - denote by *n*, and

`=MATCH(C46, INDEX('Battery Lookup Table'!B4:B36,,n),-1)` - denote by *m*

and the lookup results are then

`INDEX('Battery Lookup Table'!B4:O36,m,n)` (constant rating at required load duration) and

`INDEX('Battery Lookup Table'!A4:A36,m)`  (corresponding battery model number)

where *n* and *m* are the two cell references containing the calculated column and row numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! This was extremely informative and I got it to work after some trial and error! The only issue I ran into was m choosing the row. I made sure the table was in descending order. The match function for M should be: `=MATCH(C46, INDEX('Battery Lookup Table'!B4:O36,,n),-1)`, not to B36. The only issue I see now is a few values in the Battery Lookup table that are not in descending order no matter how I move around the rows. It's only a few values below an hour, so I really doubt it'll be much of a problem. Thank you again!

Comment: @Brandon - well spotted with the deliberate error!

Comment: I thought it seemed intentional lol. Thank you again, I couldn't have done it without your help!